# Hibernate update if unique-constraint of 2 columns gets violated

Tags: hibernate

I have a problem I cannot find any answer to.

I have an entity which has 3 members

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "col1")
private Class1 class1;

@Column(nullable = false)
private Integer lvl;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "col2")
private Class2 class2;
```

for this entitiy I want to use a unique constraint that makes sure that the combination of those 2 foreign keys can only appear once. So i added:

```
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"col1", "col2"})
})
```

above the class definition.

How can I tell hibernate to update an old entry with the new lvl when the unique constraint gets violated, and create a new row if not? Because at the moment it just throws an exception if I call saveOrUpdate()?

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: By implementing that logic by yourself. Find the entity by col1 and col2. If it exists, update it. If not, create it.

Comment: I see... I thought there was a smarter way to do this. Thanks anyways :D